# I can't pass Digest authentication, it only works in POSTMAN

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been trying to do this Digest authentication for a few days but it doesn't work if I pass the same parameters in POSTMAN it works but in React Native it doesn't. What could I be doing wrong? The problem may be in the nonce.

I made an attempt to generate the nonce and the real using WWW-Authenticate. I can now retrieve the nonce from the realm, but I was still unsuccessful:
Server response:

```
Authentication failed {"type":"default","status":401,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers":{"map":{"connection":"keep-alive", "content-length":"331","content-type":"application/json","date":"Wed, 08 Nov 2023 16:57:28 GMT","keep-alive":"timeout=5 , max=99","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block"}}, "url":"http://192.168.18.209/ISAPI/AccessControl/UserInfo/Record?format=json","bodyUsed":false,"_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":331,"offset ":0,"blobId":"5584F5A4-1C07-4299-B89E-95202A6B39EA","type":"application/json","name":"Record.json","__collector":{}}}," _bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":331,"offset":0,"blobId":"5584F5A4-1C07-4299-B89E-95202A6B39EA","type":"application/json","name" :"Record.json","__collector":{}}}}

"Digest username=\"admin\", realm=\"DS-526ECD9D\", nonce=\"MDcyMjY1YjA0ZjNjY2ZlNzkzZTQzODM5ODYzMTA4NzI=\", uri=\"http://192.168.18.209/ISAPI/AccessControl/UserInfo /Record?format=json\", algorithm=\"MD5\", qop=\"auth\", nc=\"0000001\", cnonce=\"0000001\", response=\"b88b651b10927a0b99ba26eb2cb22eba\""
```

Updated code follows:

See my last attempt passing all authentication parameters:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import md5 from 'md5';

export default function Sync() {
  const password = 'pass'; // Senha
  const username = 'admin'; // Nome de usuário
  const algorithm = 'MD5'; // Algoritmo

  const [url, setUrl] = useState('http://192.168.18.209/ISAPI/AccessControl/UserInfo/Record?format=json');

  const handleRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const initialResponse = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
      });

      if (initialResponse.status === 401) {
        const wwwAuthenticateHeader = initialResponse.headers.get('WWW-Authenticate');

        

        if (!wwwAuthenticateHeader) {
          console.log('Autenticação falhou - cabeçalho WWW-Authenticate não encontrado');
          return;
        }

        const nonceHeaderValue = initialResponse.headers.get('www-authenticate');
        const matchNonce = nonceHeaderValue && nonceHeaderValue.match(/nonce="([^"]+)"/);
        const nonce = matchNonce && matchNonce[1];

        const matchRealm = nonceHeaderValue && nonceHeaderValue.match(/realm="([^"]+)"/);
        const realm = matchRealm && matchRealm[1];

        const qop = 'auth';
        console.log('qop:', qop);

        console.log('Nonce:', nonce);
        console.log('Realm:', realm);

        const authHeader = generateDigestAuthHeader(username, password, algorithm, wwwAuthenticateHeader);

        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': authHeader,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            UserInfo: {
              employeeNo: "118",
              name: "Antonella Dantas",
              // ...
            },
          }),
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('Autenticação bem-sucedida');
        } else {
          console.log('Autenticação falhou'+JSON.stringify(response));
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Autenticação falhou - O pedido inicial não retornou um status 401');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro na solicitação GET:', error);
    }
  };

  function generateDigestAuthHeader(username, password, algorithm, wwwAuthenticateHeader) {

    const nonceHeaderValue = wwwAuthenticateHeader;
    
    const matchNonce = nonceHeaderValue && nonceHeaderValue.match(/nonce="([^"]+)"/);
    const nonce = matchNonce ? matchNonce[1] : null;

    const matchRealm = nonceHeaderValue && nonceHeaderValue.match(/realm="([^"]+)"/);
    const realm = matchRealm ? matchRealm[1] : null;

    const qop = 'auth';

    if (nonce === null || realm === null) {
      console.error('Nonce ou Realm não encontrado no cabeçalho "www-authenticate"');
      return null; // Lide com o erro conforme necessário
    }

    console.log('Nonce2:', nonce);
    console.log('Realm2:', realm);
    console.log('Qop2:', qop);

    const nc = '0000001';
    const cnonce = '0000001';
    const method = 'POST';

    const A1 = md5(username + ':' + realm + ':' + password);
    const A2 = md5(method + ':' + url);
    const response = md5(A1 + ':' + nonce + ':' + nc + ':' + cnonce + ':' + qop + ':' + md5(A2));

    return `Digest username="${username}", realm="${realm}", nonce="${nonce}", uri="${url}", algorithm="${algorithm}", qop="${qop}", nc="${nc}", cnonce="${cnonce}", response="${response}"`;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="URL"
        value={url}
        onChangeText={setUrl}
      />
      <Button title="Fazer Solicitação" onPress={handleRequest} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nonce is specified by the server in the WWW-Authenticate response header.

Comment: @user18309290 I made an attempt to generate the nonce and real using WWW-Authenticate, but they always return null

Comment: Make the exact same request (just without an authentication header) to get challenges from a server.

Comment: @user18309290 I updated the code, can you check it?

Comment: @user18309290 challenges from a server: 
Digest qop="auth", realm="DS-526ECD9D", nonce="MDcyMjY1YjA0ZjNjY2ZlNzkzZTQzODM5ODYzMTA4NzI=", stale="false", opaque="", domain="::"